# Saving slider value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uislider

I am trying to save a slider value and save it to Firebase Database. I have progressed from previous problems (Thanks Stack Overflow!) and now am uploading 'String' to the database but I want to get the value of the slider instead. I'm missing something obviously, just don't know what. I've been working on this so long so looking for someone else's perspective. I apologize for the messy code. That's what you get with newbies ;-) The code is below. Thanks for any thoughts.

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var myEmail: String?

var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
var currentValue = String.self


@IBOutlet var emailShown: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var myEmailDisplayed: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var sliderLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var verticalSlider: UISlider!

       {
            didSet{
                verticalSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

            }
    }

let img:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 180, width: 250, height: 320))

@IBAction func verticalSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        let currentValue = String(sender.value);

        sliderLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"

}


@IBAction func checkmarkButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject!) {

    //Count number of download URLs in child 'Books'



    //Use 'Post' to save currentValue variable to database by book and email

    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let currentValue = String(describing: self.currentValue)

    self.ref?.child(uuid).child("Slider Value").setValue(currentValue)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working and the code is below. Thanks for checking this out and hope it helps others.

```
 class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var myEmail: String?
    var myName: String?
    var myGender: String?
    var myLocation: String?
    var myEducation: String?
    var myRelationshipStatus: String?

    var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
    var currentValue = String.self
    var bookRating: FIRDatabaseReference!

@IBOutlet weak var emailDisplayed: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var verticalSlider: UISlider!


       {
            didSet{
                verticalSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

            }
    }

let img:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 180, width: 250, height: 320))

@IBAction func verticalSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        let currentValue = String(sender.value);

        sliderLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"

}


@IBAction func checkmarkButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject!) {

    //Count number of download URLs in child 'Books'



    //Use 'Post' to save currentValue variable to database by book and email

    //self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    //let currentValue = String(describing: self.currentValue)

    //self.ref?.child(uuid).child("Slider Value").setValue(currentValue)

    bookRating = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("ratings").child("hjayanthi@gmail.com")
    addRating()

    }

func addRating() {

    let key = bookRating.childByAutoId().key
    let rating = ["id":key, "ratingValue": sliderLabel.text! as String]
    bookRating.child(key).setValue(rating)


}



}
```